# MYSQL AND PHP FULL TEXT SEARCH

Tags: php, mysql

**I have the following two queries:**

```
$s_name = $this->input->post('check_sur_name');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE MATCH(s_name) AGAINST ('$s_name' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) or MATCH(f_name) AGAINST (''  IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $query = $query->result_array();

        echo json_encode($query);
```

**And this is the second one:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE MATCH(s_name) AGAINST ('Mugabe' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) or MATCH(f_name) AGAINST (''  IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$query = $query->result_array();

echo json_encode($query);
```

The second script runs very well and gives me a feedback but the first one keeps failing, please advise what have I done wrong in the  first script?

Comment: If you echo $s_name, what you get as result?

Comment: Print  $s_name and see what value you are getting. May this variable contain value which has single quote or double quote.